# Why is package included in Yocto rootfs?

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I'm in the process of upgrading from Yocto Sumo to Yocto Dunfell. In this process there's quite a few packages getting added to the rootfs that wasn't there before and which I don't have use for. I would like to know why they are added? Which dependency triggers them to get added?

In previous versions of Yocto there was a `pn-depends.dot` file which provided this information. This has now been removed. All that is left is a `task-depends.dot` which I guess I should use, however it is harder to read as it lists dependencies between individual tasks and doesn't show why a certain package is added to the rootfs. The command `bitbake -g <image-name> -u taskexp` makes it slightly easier to read the file but it is still hard to understand as package names are not always the same as task names.

What is the preferred solution to get an answer to "why is  included in my rootfs?"